# c++ accumulate how to apply specific function to last element

Tags: c++, stl, stl-algorithm

I have a question regarding std::accumulate.

Typically, accumulate will take a `std::vector<U> vect`, a seed of type `T` and will (left) fold the function `f` `TxU->U` for that range:

```
T result = accumulate( vect.begin(), vect.end(), seed, f);
```

Is there a natural way to apply a specific version of `f` for the last element?
This is for a PDE, I have a special condition for the final step.

We can do something like:

```
T result1 = accumulate( vect.begin(), vect.end()-1, seed, f1);
T result2 = f2( result1, vect.back() );
```

But I'm wondering if there is a more natural way since f2 is actually a special case of f1.

Thanks

Comment: Your version seems natural for me (assuming `vect` is not empty).

Comment: I'd even say that anything else would be less clear.

Comment: "and will (left) fold the function `f` `TxU->U` ...". Either your brain has been damaged by Haskel or mine by C++. I cannot decide which, so it is probably mine.

Comment: I go to Haskell Anonymous...

Answer (score 0):

Your implementation is fine, but you can achieve what you need with a functor,

```
class myFunctor{
  int size_of_vector;
  int nbCalls;
  myFunctor(int size) : size_of_vector(size), nbCalls(0){}
  ... operator()(...) {
    if((nbCalls++)==size_of_vector)
       // call special function
    else
       // call f
  }
};
```

and then use it like this :

```
T result1 = accumulate( vect.begin(), vect.end(), seed, myFunction(vect.size()));
```

I am not sure if this works, but it doesn't look good anyway

Answer (score 0):

Based on the answers:

The implementation is clear and natural. The vector must be non-empty.

Comment: "To avoid segmentation fault" is a bizarre and terrible motivation for anything. You program because you want to *achieve* a certain goal, not because you want to *avoid* suffering from a mistake. The vector must be non-empty because non-emtpiness is a requirement of the stated goal!